Inequality :$\sum_{cyc}x^2(x-y)(x-2y)\ge 0\forall x,y,z\,\,\in\mathbb{R}$
$\sum_{cyc}x^2(x-y)(x-2y)\ge 0\,\,\forall x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$
My attempt : WLOG let $|z|=\max\{|x|,|y|,|z|\}$
$|z|=0\implies x=y=z=0$ Done!!
Let $|z|>0$
Dividing whole inequality by $z^4$ and assuming $\frac xz=a, \frac yz=t,|a|\le 1,|t|\le1$ we get on LHS,
$t^4-3t^3+2(a^2+1)t^2-3a^3t+(a^4+2a^2-3a+1)$
Consider: $f(t)= t^4-3t^3+2(a^2+1)t^2-3a^3t+(a^4+2a^2-3a+1);\,\,t,a\in[-1,1].$
Let us prove $f(t)\ge 0\,\,\forall t\in[-1,1]$

With the help of CAS (Computer Algebra System), here is an SOS (sum of squares) expression: $\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}x^2(x-y)(x-2y) = \frac14, \left( 2,{x}^{2}-3,xy-{y}^{2}+3,yz-{z}^{2} \right) ^{2}+\frac34,
\left( xy-2,xz-{y}^{2}+yz+{z}^{2} \right) ^{2}$.
